# В зависимости от переменной объявлять нужный класс

Tags: c#, asp

подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать обьявление классов более лучше?

Пример:
Есть переменная:
`string type = "...";`

И есть к примеру 3 класса:

```cs
public class Test1
{
    ...
}

public class Test2
{
    ...
}

public class Test3
{
    ...
}
```

С суть проста: в зависимости от того что находится в type, в зависимости от этого обьявлять тот или иной класс.

Я могу реализовать конечно вот так:

```cs
switch(type)
{
    case "Test1":
        Test1 test = new Test1();
        break;

    case "Test2":
        Test2 test = new Test2();
        break;
  
    case "Test3":
        Test3 test = new Test3();
        break;
    
    default:
        break;
}
```

Вопрос крайне простой:
Возможно ли это реализовать проще и желательно без if/switch?

Comment: [Замена условного оператора полиморфизмом](https://refactoring.guru/ru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)

Comment: Если строка совпадает с именем класса switch можно заменить с помощью  `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: Откуда взялось вот это: `string type = "..."`. Нет, вы не поняли: откуда оно _изначально_ взялось? И опять вы не туда смотрите. До объявления переменной `type` у вас что есть? Ещё дальше смотрите, ещё дальше! Я на 99,(9)% уверен, что проблема решается намного выше по коду.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кусочек [отсюда](https://refactoring.guru/ru/smells/switch-statements)

> **Не стоит трогать, если...**
>
> - Когда оператор switch выполняет простые действия, нет никакого смысла    что-то менять в коде.
> - Зачастую оператор switch используется в фабричных паттернах    проектирования (Фабричный метод, Абстрактная фабрика) для выбора
>   создаваемого класса.